# Are there alternatives to constexpr with character pointer array definitions in C++11 and C++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

I have some code that I use to give me a list of strings than match the names of enum members so that I can parse text files that use the names easily into the enums. (I actually generate it automatically with a macro but that is a different story.) The code works fine on modern compilers running C++17 but one of my target platforms does not have C++17 support and I'd like to come up with an alternative that works on C++14 (and ideally C++11). The current code is:

```
class A 
{
    enum MatchType { Linear, Square };
    static constexpr const char * matchTypeStrings[ 2 ] = { "Linear", "Square" };
    static const size_t matchTypeCount = 2;
};
```

I'd rather not give the enum global scope because that never ends well, and ideally I don't want to add anything to one of the .cpp files (which of course will fix the linker error, but I think it isn't recommended for C++17 code, and won't work with my macro anyway). I was whether I could create a member function that could return the string value instead but I can't think of a neat way of doing it.

Comment: Can you please show us how you use the existing code and the exact errors you get when you try to port it to C++14 or 11?

Comment: Yes, I get a linker error: undefined reference to `A::matchTypeStrings'. It's because under C++14 I need to instantiate matchTypeStrings outside the class definition (unless I'm lucky and the compiler optimisation inlines everything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a static member function:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

class A 
{
public:
    enum MatchType { Linear, Square };
    static const char * matchTypeStrings(MatchType type)
    {
        static const char * const matchTypeStrings[ 2 ] = { "Linear", "Square" };
        return matchTypeStrings[type];
    }
    static const std::size_t matchTypeCount = 2;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::matchTypeStrings(A::Linear) << '\n';
    std::cout << A::matchTypeStrings(A::Square) << '\n';
}
```

It is important to note that this obviously is not constexpr, however GCC and Clang manage to generate similar code with optimizations enabled. ( On Compiler Explorer: [Your version](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BOLh1T7ZrlerY2DMaJIz6rBAIwsI1IphGG3XqBXqZkcitAyGyMkZk464IK%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%2BAvJ84J/MCsxguV6Rwsi6LYrSYJNG0Tq0rsHrSoK6JgktnL0harLyriqq2kthqPYqF2%2BvamqwhSgP2niW3%2Bv6QZhoj0DxsgncV2m2b5upBXgBmMxn1WiLtvwIhmXGVLLtJ4jTvGMwLquuRbvF%2B7vufCxAM4d8vA2QD33fbhyPPeWAYgyaV1BxDkJvSH4AgJAky%2BAh4cIkukfMaw85IQQLKl6yuF4AB3PTfCM0bV374GV3LmYt8IBAZiTuaFpR9PM%2Bzmubzr9bAPmixJEAl7JHfRvJC8XgoFAbx2goPRQYMR6oXQtDKeLZZ6IxIhqTAy82prysjLbeu997/UPkDKCMFxjSnPgQS%2B18U5LRWmtDaT9Fz3UkIhIBR98FgPgsPO6ODJBMITrBcGtdSAKRxmbbgQA%3D%3D), [Static function](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BqFcL1%2BOGhMlT3x60lJJlcspBEmCxAID8AC9MAB9dNqlkCvQGeimyaSd0PN0xs5nWxF5i2CAi2uxqXoLNoAzpmY6Ae3LPFwOa4PaiBrLPWjq7QezSZgIa6nS0Zc1ol/TMoHr92ZD6cgUcarWhqdZx3YucDocb1frob12u4gZdVggAa6gakUwDdw/qgn6DjIcgZj0fTwpIwycD%2BBCfgBHRdAA1mYACcAB07gABzuJw2FoY8wzQWhurQcMQiftwP5/gBpBAQMP4KCAnjwf%2Bb6kHAsBIGgRheHg7BkBQEC8fxgkgMA3DYRRVACQQrjMRATgIT%2BTi2Bk0KfrBpC8UYWgEAA8rQrCaexpBYEyojsCp5l4IcKQAG6YMxZmYAAHskfaDHRTbKDZnxOMQGl6FgWlwRyRgqV0ND0EwbAcDw/BmEIIhiHIchCHgTjMZAXSoF4hQuQAtAsMy4hIoEyJwnCTEVBnDExSQpBoECWHUpgJJYZQxHEoS%2BP4dDtX14QBN1FTxIkBSpE0Q0NE1hTFJkY1tBNJK1PoOSCGtzTRONXBdAoEH9PtlFfjRNkMW52EAGxFdd3CTMAyCytwGHYRhwyTBAuCECQFowaieh8QJrj/ZIc4gbIMhwVFKFcJh3CEZI7hke4KNoZwurcLwH4DNRv4XZ%2BTEsaQbGIZxMCILuwOCeQlCiSDbiXKIwzcAksmsPJxCKcpZlqbQGlhTpqBGHp9BGSZNkWal1lmfg9lqE5Ll0e5nnyTZvm43RAVBcQ0IhYM2kTpF7HRXQjAsNZiUCBRwiiCg6UyJl2XwHlBUBMVpXDOVjvSNVtX1Y1U0tW1G0hBRXUtD1lTDLq3j9YUQ3mGEA20MtvWx5NyQLTNYemBR%2BTZ9NJTpzHcfbUn1Ql1He2xwdR0Je%2Bn7fgTZmXTdd0PczwCTMMGGvTV334EQxD/QkkxA2JoMjMMEO%2BzDptw5wmHXe4pGkfdwzEdw7jcHHuP47RgFE4oJNkxxXFU3ubwEHTIki1PbgR8PJCCDFFvxVwvAAO5BV4YVNzOq3OiDEZ6TG/oQBAkwrq3XuuSO2Pc%2B4DwXohJenA3qcGGGjNC3BoLXQIvhcwB9zptxPsxViUUKbwAgEga%2BfY74M3EuYTAL8JrvzilbH%2Bf8AGnRbkfein4RiGggQQKBMDO6PWepMV670Gqk1hqQVCyNTqH0JoxU%2BFDF6nUkCQkBJ9z5IVIE5bmAQQDcCAA%3D) )

Comment: This works brilliantly. All I needed to change in my code is [] to () and it now compiles on C++14. I ended up creating 2 versions in the macro so I could use both size_t and enum as indices without warnings. Tested on g++ 6.4 and Visual C++ 2017.